# use win32gui in python for background mouse click to a window

Tags: python, mouseevent, win32gui

I'm trying to build a bot to automate some actions in a mobile game that I'm running on my pc through Noxplayer.

I would like to open multiple gaming windows and keep the window background.

The following code works but it will bring the window to the foreground.

```
import pywinauto
import time

handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(best_match='my_window')[0]
app = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(handle=handle)
window = app.window()
window.click_input(button = 'left', coords = (350, 250))
time.sleep(0.5)
window.click_input(button = 'left', coords = (850, 450))
```

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9F_ZKaYCN4) and tried the following code but I have no idea why it does not work.

```
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con
import time

def click(x, y):
    handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "my_window")
    handle = win32gui.FindWindowEx(handle, None, None, None)

    position = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)
    win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, position)
    win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, None, position)
    time.sleep(0.1)

click(350, 250)
click(850, 450)
```

I also tried other function like `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle)` and it will bring the window to foreground, but `win32gui.SendMessage` still not works.

Comment: `it does not work` – what's the error?

Comment: no error and there is noting happened